# What was used to obfuscate this Javascript or how can I deobfuscate it?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I would appreciate if someone could identify what tool or process may have been used to obfuscate two files.

It is actually code that we hired an HTML5 developer to create.  On delivery, some of the .js code was obfuscated.  I did specify that we would get the source code, but for various reasons, I don't want to force that, at least not right now.  I don't need to edit the source code yet, but I want to know my options and perhaps simplify the situation.

Here are small excerpts from the two files

data.js (from the start of the file)

```
{"project": [null,null,[[0,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],[1,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],[2,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],[3,false,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false],[4,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],[5,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false],[6,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false],[7,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false],[8,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]],[["t0",5,false,[],0,0,null,[["Default",5,false,1,0,false,3756169185149289,[["imgs/bg-sheet0.png",45907,0,0,1105,500,1,0.5004525184631348,0.5,[],[],0]]]],[],false,false,5609930934870015,[],null],["t1",5,false,[],0,0,null,[["Default",30,false,1,0,false,6181700866648787,[["imgs/m-sheet0.png",3199641,1,1,337,500,1,0.501483678817749,0.5,[],[],0],["imgs/m-sheet0.png",3199641,340,1,337,500,1,0.501483678817749,0.5,[],[],0],["imgs/m-sheet0.png",3199641,679,1,337,500,1,0.501483678817749,0.5,[],[],0],["imgs/m-sheet0.png",3199641,1018,1,337,500,1,0.501483678817749,0.5,[],[],0],["imgs/m-sheet0.png",3199641,1357,1,337,500,1,0.501483678817749,0.5,[],[],0],["imgs/m-sheet0.png",3199641,1696,1,337,500,1,0.501483678817749,0.5,[],[],0],["imgs/m-sheet0.png",3199641,1,503,337,500,1,0.501483678817749,0.5,[],[],0],[.....
```

runtime.js (also from the start of the file)

```
'use strict';var ba,ca,da,ea,fa,ga,B,ha,ja,ka,la,ma,na,oa,pa,qa,ta,ua,va,wa,xa,ya,Aa,Ba,O,Da,Ea,Fa,Ga,Ha,R,Ia,Ja,Ka,La,Na,Oa,Pa,Qa,Ra,Sa,Ta,Ua,Va,ab,bb,cb,db,eb,fb,gb,hb,ib,jb,kb,lb,nb,ob,pb,qb,rb,sb,tb,ub,vb,wb,xb,yb,zb,Ab,Bb,Cb,Db,Fb,Gb,Hb,Ib,Jb,Kb,Lb,Mb,Nb,Ob,Pb,Qb,Rb,Sb,Tb,Ub,Vb,Wb,Xb,Yb,Zb,$b,ac,bc,cc,dc,ec,fc,gc,hc,ic={},jc={};"function"!==typeof Object.getPrototypeOf&&(Object.getPrototypeOf="object"===typeof"test".__proto__?function(g){return g.__proto__}:function(g){return g.constructor.prototype});
(function(){function g(a,x,b,f){this.set(a,x,b,f)}function q(){this.xc=this.wc=this.zc=this.yc=this.Oc=this.Nc=this.gc=this.fc=0}function l(a,x,b,f){a<x?b<f?(y=a<b?a:b,p=x>f?x:f):(y=a<f?a:f,p=x>b?x:b):b<f?(y=x<b?x:b,p=a>f?a:f):(y=x<f?x:f,p=a>b?a:b)}function h(){this.items=this.ie=null;this.yi=0;I&&(this.ie=new Set);this.Gh=[];this.ef=!0}function e(a){P[w++]=a}function r(){this.R=this.jl=this.y=this.Rl=0}function c(a){this.qh=[];this.dp=this.fp=this.gp=this.ep=0;this.ej(a)}function b(a,x){this.Xl=a;this.Wl=x;this.cells={}}function t(a,x){this.Xl=;this.Wl=x;this.cells={}}function d(a,x,b){var f;return A.length?(f=A.pop(),f.Km=a,f.x=x,f.y=b,f):new ba(a,x,b)}function a(a,x,b){this.Km=a;this.x=x;this.y=b;this.Ab=new ca}function f(a,x,b){var f;return D.length?(f=D.pop(),f.Km=a,f.x=x,f.y=b,f):new da(a,x,b)}function m(a,x,b){this.Km=a;this.x=x;this.y=b;this.Ab=[];this.Ug=!0;this.fe=new ca;this.Lh=!1}function k(a,x){return a.Pd-x.Pd}ea=function(a){window.console&&window.console.log&&window.console.log(a)};

And from the end of the same file

h.zz=function(e){this.r=e};h.kz=function(e){this.Wh=e};h.sz=function(e){this.J=e};h.rz=function(e,g,c,b,l,d,a,f){this.r=e;this.J=g;this.Wh=c;h.Pt.apply(this,[b]);h.Tt.apply(this,[l]);h.Nt.apply(this,[d]);h.Yt.apply(this,[a]);this.Rb=f;this.zf()};q.eb={};q=q.eb;q.$y=function(e){e.u(this.L/(this.duration+this.na+this.Fa))};q.az=function(e){e.u(this.L)};q.Ps=function(e){e.u(this.duration)};q.Ey=function(e){e.u(this.na)};q.yy=function(e){e.u(this.Fa)};q.Gz=function(e){e.Nb(this.target)};q.Jz=function(e){e.u(this.value)};q.ag=function(e){e.Ea(this.ag?1:0)}})();functionc()return[tc,uc,wc,vc,sc,Z,zc,xc,yc,Ec,Ac,Fc,X.prototype.g.yo,zc.prototype.F.As,zc.prototype.g.Ns,zc.prototype.F.Ko,zc.prototype.F.Ho,zc.prototype.F.Io,zc.prototype.F.Jo,zc.prototype.F.ro,X.prototype.g.Dt,Z.prototype.F.Os,X.prototype.F.du,zc.prototype.F.Rt,Fc.prototype.F.Ut,Fc.prototype.F.Vt,Fc.prototype.F.Mo,Ac.prototype.F.$t,X.prototype.g.Ws,wc.prototype.g.Ys,Z.prototype.g.Ts,Z.prototype.F.Lt,X.prototype.g.cu,tc.prototype.F.Play,X.prototype.g.so,wc.prototype.F.Mt,wc.prototype.g.Dl,yc.prototype.g.Fl,sc.prototype.F.CallFunction,Z.prototype.F.Kt,X.prototype.F.Ot,X.prototype.F.Wt,X.prototype.g.Ks,Z.prototype.F.Zt,Z.prototype.F.St,Z.prototype.g.Xs,X.prototype.F.Gt,X.prototype.F.It,uc.prototype.F.Ss,X.prototype.F.Ms,Z.prototype.F.Qt,Z.prototype.eb.Hl,Ec.prototype.F.Et,Z.prototype.g.to,Ac.prototype.F.Ht,Z.prototype.g.Js,Fc.prototype.g.wo,Z.prototype.g.Hs,Z.prototype.g.Ls,X.prototype.F.Bs,X.prototype.F.au,Z.prototype.g.Is,sc.prototype.g.xj]};
```

Comment: note im not a lawyer, but if it was in your contract, then you should ensure that the person correctly delivers.

Comment: this is not an obfuscated code at all :)

Comment: Daniel, I still need to be able to get his help in the short run while his app is integrated into the website proper (and I willingly pay for it where appropriate).  Demanding the source code before then could jeopardize that, otherwise I would.

Comment: I spend hours researching this topic on the web before asking.  I was hoping someone would be able to say, "I recognize that, it's....".  Now I can't post for a while because the question was repeatedly down-voted.  Would you guys please let me know what I should have said/asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools available to help deobfuscate code, plugins like [javascript-deobfuscator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/) and websites such as [this](http://www.jsnice.org) and [this](http://jsbeautifier.org) can help in the process but sometimes if the obfuscation is incredibly complex or too deep some people have noted problems with performance etc.

As to what tool was used to obfuscate the code that list is also potentially very large as for many people obfuscation is common practice to protect the code as well as to reduce the memory requirement of a script. They are also widely available like [this](https://javascriptobfuscator.com) and [this](http://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/). It really depends on the level of obfuscation they wanted to reach.

here are some other popular options for obfuscation:

[YUI Compressor](https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

[Google closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)

[JSSCrambler](https://jscrambler.com/en/)